# Prove the following using induction on d (matrices)

Tags: matrices, induction, exponentiation

[image]

I manage to reach the step where I need to prove n = k + 1 but I am battling to complete the proof as I am not certain what to do with the exponents in my answer.

I will run through the proof as I have done it step by step.

1) Basis Step: n = 1

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^n$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^{n-1}&2^{n-1}\\2^{n-1}&2^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

Thus: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^1$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^{1-1}&2^{1-1}\\2^{1-1}&2^{1-1}\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^0&2^0\\2^0&2^0\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

2) I assume n = k and insert k where I see n

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^k$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^{k-1}&2^{k-1}\\2^{k-1}&2^{k-1}\end{bmatrix}$

3) I now know I want to show that

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^{(k+1)-1}&2^{(k+1)-1}\\2^{(k+1)-1}&2^{(k+1)-1}\end{bmatrix}$

so I must prove by induction that n = k + 1

This is as far as I get but I am struggling with arranging the exponents in such a way that I reach

Here are my workings:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{k}$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^{k-1}&2^{k-1}\\2^{k-1}&2^{k-1}\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}(2^{k-1})(1)+(2^{k-1})(1)&2^{k-1})(1)+(2^{k-1})(1)\\2^{k-1})(1)+(2^{k-1})(1)&2^{k-1})(1)+(2^{k-1})(1)\end{bmatrix}$

I finally get $\begin{bmatrix}2^{k}&2^{k}\\2^{k}&2^{k}\end{bmatrix}$ and I am looking to get  $\begin{bmatrix}2^{(k+1)-1}&2^{(k+1)-1}\\2^{(k+1)-1}&2^{(k+1)-1}\end{bmatrix}$

What rule am I missing regarding exponents here that I should be using to get k + 1 or have a made a mistake while proving these matrices by induction?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Wait, isn't $2^k=2^{(k+1)-1}$?

Comment: LOL, $2^k = 2^{(k+1)-1}$

Comment: @Scounged I feel very silly round about now O_o so this is correct. LOL Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the multiplication wrong. You should get:
$$
2^{k-1}·1 + 2^{k-1}·1 = 2·2^{k-1} = 2^k = 2^{(k + 1) - 1}
$$
Remember to add the two products, since it is a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I amended this now.